# how to go to particular column in csv file and print the whole row if in column value is less than particular value

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file which contains 4 rows and 26 columns. I need to go to 22 column and if the values in that column are less than 0.5, I need to grep the whole row of that particular value using python

**the code which i tried**

df=pd.read_csv("trial.txt",delimiter='\t')

a=df[df['col_22'] < 0.5]

print a

**but when i am executing the code the value of the 1 and last column of that row are only printing but not values of the other columns of that row,but i want to print the all 26 column values of that row in a txt file
**

Comment: What have you tried yet?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('your csv file path')

df.loc[df.col_22 < 0.5]
```

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['john','anna','goli'],
    'age':[34,27,45]})
print(df.loc[df.age==45])
```

**Output:**

```
  name  age
2  goli   45
```

Comment: in df as  i have 22 columns it is not printing all the columns it is printing only first and second columns

Comment: @AlekhyaVemula if the answer has helped you. Please consider upvoting and accept the answer